# Can't set the strategy="moving-window" for Flask-Limiter

Tags: python, flask, redis, server

I want to limit IP connection to a server (currently implemented locally). 
Here is my code

```
  from flask import Flask, request
  from flask.ext.cors import CORS, cross_origin
  import time
  import redis
  from flask.ext.limiter.extension import  Limiter
  from flask.ext.limiter.util import get_ipaddr


  app = Flask(__name__)
  cors=CORS(app)


  limiter = Limiter(
  app,
  key_func=get_ipaddr,
  global_limits=[str(LIMITPERDAY) + " per day", str(LIMITPERMINUTE) + " per       minute"],
  storage_uri ="redis://127.0.0.1:6379",
  #strategy="moving-window",
  headers_enabled=True  
 )


  @app.errorhandler(429)
  def ratelimit_handler(e):
       return "Ratelimit exceeded : " + e.description, 429

  if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=10005,threaded=True )
```

If I comment out the strategy part, when I connect to the server using curl or plain html, I keep getting error 500: Internal Server Error. When I comment out the strategy, the code can work. However from what I read in 
http://flask-limiter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask_limiter.Limiter
I need to use "moving-window" to connect to redis, otherwise it's "fixed-window" by default. I really don't know what's wrong with my code. 
I run redis-server on Windows 10. I run my Flask on cygwin-64.
Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get in your logs?

Comment: My guess is the `LIMITPERDAY` is potentially blowing it up— you don't seem to set the value for that in your code.

Comment: @MattHealy, I got this  
raise response
ResponseError: unknown command 'EVALSHA'   I believe it's because of Redis version incompability.

Comment: @lita it seems like your redis version is out of date - see https://github.com/nvie/rq/issues/398

Comment: @MattHealy, thanks. I found the same link via Google but I can't copy paste it since I'm not familiar with the markup syntax in StackOverflow yet.

Comment: @Doobeh, I have set LIMITPERDAY = 20 but I didn't put it in the question here. I think it's the Redis incompabilty problem.

Comment: I have fixed the problem by installing a newer version of Redis. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

After I activate the debug, I found out the error is

```
      File "C:\Users\lita\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py",        line     582, in read_response
         raise response
      ResponseError: unknown command 'EVALSHA'
```

I check on https://github.com/nvie/rq/issues/398 and it's because  Redis >= 2.6.0 is required. After I upgrade my Redis, the problem is solved.